# HTTP 400 following validation failure Spring MVC

Tags: forms, validation, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-form

We are using Spring MVC 3.2.4 with spring form tags and JSTL core tags inside a multipart form (for optional file upload). We have a form backing object for view binding that is passed via the controller. This form object is then validated in a custom validator implementing the Spring Framework Validator.

When a user submits the form without a required field the form is returned with errors via  . When the user corrects the missing field and resubmits the response is a 400 error stating "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect()." with no additional stacktrace or error.

This behavior is further isolated to form elements that are bound to List objects rather than String objects (i.e. `<input name="address[x]" />` where x is the number of address inputs). Has anyone seen similar behavior?

Regards

Comment: Set your log level to trace or debug and try again.

Comment: It is a type mismatch error when returning from validation. The id is set to null. I'm looking at a way to set the value via js. Thanks for the reminder, could've sworn it was already set to DEBUG, though...

Comment: After further analysis it appears it was an invention of my own doing. When the user submits the form for validation it goes though the workflow as if it is going to be persisted. When the form returns it is passed though a custom tag file. If the object isn't persisted the id field is null and is added bound to the value attribute as "null." Spring chokes on this value as it cannot be parsed to an Integer as the persistence entity expects...